# Exclusão Lista e Retorno

Tags: python, string, lista

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será passado como
entrada a lista com as informações atuais de um contato, e o telefone que se deseja excluir:

• caso o telefone esteja na lista de telefones do contato, ele deve ser removido.

• caso não esteja, nenhuma atualização será feita.

Oque fazer para obter a saída esperada da função “exclusão”?

```
def contato(nome,telefone='()',email='()',instagram='()'):

    '''Dados nome, telefone, email e instragram-->str. Retorna uma lista com os dados informados'''
    lista=[nome,[telefone],[email],[instagram]]
    return lista

def exclusão(lista, telefone):

    '''Dado o nome e numero de telefone, retorna a lista sem o numero de telefone informado'''
    P= lista
    B= telefone
    A= P[1]
    if (B in A):
        del(lista[2])
        return lista
    if (B not in A):
        return lista

# Entrada: contato('henrique','22222','nada','@123')
# Valor Esperado: ['henrique', ['22222'], ['nada'], ['@123']]

# Entrada: exclusão('henrique','22222')
# Valor Esperado: ['henrique',['nada'], ['@123']]
# Valor Obtido: 'henrique'
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Ok, vou colocar, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Boa noite, a pergunta séria= Oque fazer para obter a saída esperada da função “exclusão”? Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema está sendo você redefinir a variável `lista` no parâmetro da função `exclusão`, substitua 'lista' por 'nome', e onde `del(lista[2])` por `del(lista[1])` que é o índice do telefone na lista.

Defina a variável `lista` como variável **global** para que possa ser utilizada nas outras funções.

Você não precisa colocar entre parênteses as condições da fórmula `if`, também não precisa adicionar outra condição `if` caso o telefone não esteja na lista.

Seu código fica assim:

```py
def contato(nome,telefone='()',email='()',instagram='()'):
    global lista
    '''Dados nome, telefone, email e instragram-->str. Retorna uma lista com os dados informados'''
    lista=[nome,[telefone],[email],[instagram]]
    return lista

def exclusão(nome, telefone):
    '''Dado o nome e numero de telefone, retorna a lista sem o numero de telefone informado'''
    P = lista
    B = telefone
    A = P[1]
    if B in A:
        del(lista[1])
    return lista
```